# Insertion sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, insertion-sort

can somebody please help me? I must make a code of Insertion sort in C for sorting 10, 20, 50,.... numbers and I have to use random number generator rand(). I think of it really long time and still cannot get it. I found some code where you can choose the numbers. Sorry for my bad english.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int myarray[10];
    int i, j, n, temp;

    /* Get number of elements in the array */
    printf("Enter number of elements in the array \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    /* Read elements of the array */
    printf("Enter the array elements \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &myarray[i]);

    /* Sort elements of the array */
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (myarray[j - 1] > myarray[j])) {
            temp = myarray[j - 1];
            myarray[j - 1] = myarray[j];
            myarray[j] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }

    /* Print the sorted array */
    printf("Sorted Array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d \n", myarray[i]);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the random number generator instead of entering from the keyboard, add some library headers and replace your three lines of code that input numbers where I commented. I also added a line that prevents array overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                     // added library header
#include <time.h>                       // added library header

int main()
{
    int myarray[10];
    int i, j, n, temp;

    /* Get number of elements in the array */
    printf("Enter number of elements in the array \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n < 1 || n > 10)                     // check range of elements
        exit(1);

    /* Read elements of the array */
    srand((unsigned)(time(NULL)));          // seed the random generator
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)                 // each element
        myarray[i] = rand();                // assign a random number

    /* Sort elements of the array */
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (myarray[j - 1] > myarray[j])) {
            temp = myarray[j - 1];
            myarray[j - 1] = myarray[j];
            myarray[j] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }

    /* Print the sorted array */
    printf("Sorted Array\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d \n", myarray[i]);
    return 0;
}
```